# In map reduce, why to make input split size smaller than block size

Tags: dictionary, input, split, size, reduce

I am new to map reduce and have done lot of reading but unable to understand why input split size need to be made smaller than block size. Most of the material on this topic seem to be addressing the HOW and not the WHY.

So if you have block size of 64MB and a file of 512MB which will create 8 blocks, and say you have this on a cluster with 16 cores available for MR. Then I can imagine it may make sense to use all available cores and spawn 16 map tasks in parallel by using a split size of 32MB instead of using the default split size = block size which will spawn only 8 map tasks in parallel. Is this a reason to use smaller split size ? If so, then how does the actual splitting occur ? Will the framework cut the block in half and feed the two halves to two map tasks in parallel ?

Appreciate any guidance on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am new to MR as well. I guess a possible reason is as follows. The size of splits needs to maximize the locality of clusters. If the split size is larger than the block size, it is likely that one split is located in different nodes. In that case, data of nodes in different machines will be transmitted to the node in which the first node is located (the mapper is in that node as well), which increases the latency.